# vulnerabilities, packages looking for founding, npm warn notsup

Tags: css, node.js, npm, webpack, sass

Trying to install Material Design's Web Components (You’ll need all of these Node dependencies:

webpack: Bundles Sass and JavaScript
webpack-dev-server: Development server
sass-loader: Webpack loader to preprocess Sass files
sass: Sass compiler
css-loader: Resolves CSS @import and url() paths
extract-loader: Extracts the CSS into a .css file
file-loader: Serves the .css file as a public URL)
But when I try to install them I get this

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"12.13.0","npm":"6.14.5"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0

- extract-loader@5.1.0
- sass-loader@9.0.1
- file-loader@6.0.0
- css-loader@3.6.0
- sass@1.26.10
- webpack-dev-server@3.11.0
- webpack-cli@3.3.12
- webpack@4.43.0
  updated 8 packages and audited 737 packages in 18.211s

4 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 155 low severity vulnerabilities
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

I am new to using NPM, nodes, and most of this. Help would be very appreciated.
Anytime I try to use `npm install` for anything I get a message like this

Comment: its normal, my last nuxt install 56k vulnerabilities and 105 packages begging for money. To fix it clearly say in the message `npm audit fix`, run it

Comment: additionally, there's a lodash dependency that has a lower level "low" threat vulnerability that has basically bled through almost every package out there, so currently this vulnerability message is extra annoying these days.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Thank you. Ran 'npm audit fix' and this popped up 'fixed 0 of 155 vulnerabilities in 737 scanned packages
  155 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated' -